# CrystalReport - Crosstab error "A print time formula that modifies variables is used in a char or map"

Tags: crystal-reports

I got this formula in my report called "afterDAY_X_CODE":

```
global StringVar tester;
EvaluateAfter ({Command.cody});
EvaluateAfter ({@DAY_X_CODE});
if {@DAY_X_CODE} = "###Reset###" then
    tester:="reset"
else
if isnull({Command.cody})then
     if previous({@Actual_Valid_Code}) <>"NO" then
            tester:=previous({@Actual_Valid_Code})
        else
            tester
else
    if {Command.mtime}<= "04:00:00" AND NOT isnull({Command.mtime}) then
         tester:= {Command.cody}
    else
        if previous({@Actual_Valid_Code}) <>"NO" then
            tester:=previous({@Actual_Valid_Code})
        else
            tester;
```

Than I've added another formula called "SE_VALUATOR":

```
evaluateafter ({@afterDAY_X_CODE});
if {@afterDAY_X_CODE} = "XXXX" then
    1
else
    0
```

When I try to create a cross tab into Report Header, using "SE_VALUATOR" into Summarized Field I got the following error message:

"A print time formula that modifies variableas is used in a chart or map Details: @afterDAY_X_CODE"

[image]
[image]

Any idea/workaround on how to avoid this error?
Thank in advance.
Regards.

Comment: When does your evaluate before ir after the evaluate formula and also where are you using your formula that is in evaluate after

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment, could you please explain me more? thx

Comment: I guess your formula in evaluate after is not accessable for your firmula that is why i am asking wherr you placed the firmula

Comment: Do you know if there's any workaround? Even If try to remove EvaluateAfter from formulas it generate same error.

Comment: Can you show me screen shot of the report where exactly you are using formulas

Comment: Added in my question above: cross-table is in the report Header section.Thank you.